# Promise Rejection: FooService not defined

Tags: angular

I am not even using the FooService, but Angular 2 wants to complain.

```
export class DisplayFooComponent implements OnInit {

private foo: Foo;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
// this.getFoo();
this.foo.name = "Bar Test";
} 

// getFoo() : void {
//   this.fooService.getFoo()
//     .then(foo => this.foo = foo);
// }
}
```

I have chased this for a few hours. Everything that references the service is gone, but it still complains that it's not defined and it won't show anything on the page (because Angular 2 is erroring out)

However if I do:

```
export class DisplayFooComponent implements OnInit {

private foo: Foo;

constructor(private fooService:FooService) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.getFoo();
//this.foo.name = "Bar Test";
} 

 getFoo() : void {
   this.fooService.getFoo()
     .then(foo => this.foo = foo);
 }
}
```

I still get an error that the service is not defined, however it uses my service, makes an http call and still gets Foo.

I think I am missing something really simple here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.20.5 to 1.0.0-beta.21 seems to have fixed it.  Now behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you insert a FooService in providers: [ ]?

exemple:

```
@Component({
    providers: [FooService],
    templateUrl: './youTemplate.html'

})
```

You must also import the file:

```
import {FooService}  from 'youPath/fooService';
```

You should also import in module:

```
import {FooService}  from 'youPath/fooService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ .... ],
  declarations: [ .... ],
  providers:[ FooService ]
})
```

Comment: I have those as well, I just did not include them in the code snippet.